# Count occurences of elements and sum up its value in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 2 columns (Company and Amount). There are multiple companies (string) and a value in another column as numeric.

I want to count all the companies sum the amount for each company.
So in the end I want to have a new data frame with 3 columns (Company, Occurrences, Total Amount)

[image]

I could count all the occurrences and saved it in a new data frame but have no idea how to get the amount.

```
library(dplyr)
df_companies %>% count(df_companies$Geldgeber) %>% top_n(3, n) %>% arrange(desc(n))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `n()` to get the count

```
library(dplyr)

df_companies %>%
  group_by(Geldgeber) %>%
  summarize(ct = n(), total = sum(Betrag))
```

You will want to consider how to account for missing values in `Betrag`, if any. For example, you could initially `filter(!is.na(Betrag))`, or you can use `na.rm=T` in the call to `sum()`

Comment: Ah thanks! Is it possible to sort them by occurrences of the companies?

Comment: add `%>% arrange(ct)` or `%>% arrange(desc(ct))` at the end of the above pipeline